# how to stop xmlstarlet messing which whitepace

Tags: xmlstarlet

The following cli looks like it just tells xmlstarlet to edit one specific xpath.

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -N p=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -u '/p:project/p:parent/p:version' -v 1.2.3 pom.xml
```

but actually it edits all the whitespace nodes in the whole document.

Is there any way to tell xmlstarlet only to change specific nodes.